# How to solve tm_shape overwriting a value within a county

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to build a rather simple map with tm_shape. I want to include the numerical values in the entities they describe. In other words, I have a map of the German Bundesländer (counties) and specific values for each of them. But Berlin and Bandenburg have the same geographical centre which is why tm_shape overwrites one of the values with the other.

I have also tried to It set auto.placement = TRUE but the values are not identifiable for the Bundesländer either then.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)

options(scipen = 999)

mydata2 <- read.csv("myfile.csv")

mymap2 <- st_read("DEU_adm1.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mapdata2 <- inner_join(mymap2, mydata2)

tm_shape(mapdata2) +
  tm_polygons("Kirchenzugehörige", id = "NAME_1", palette = "Greys") +
  tm_layout(bg.color = "white", inner.margins = c(0, .04, .1, .16),
            frame = FALSE, title = "Prozent der Bevölkerung zugehörig zu einer christlichen Kirche") +
  tm_text("Kirchenzugehörige",size = 0.5, auto.placement = F)
```

The values are any values for any of the 16 Bundesländer.

Say

[image]

The map looks as follows:

[image]

Brandenburg to the east, Berlin right in its centre.

I would just need to write the Brandenburg value separate from Berlin, in the Brandenburg Bundesland (county).

I would also go without the values within the map and a legend that specifically assigns the value to each county on the side.

Comment: Could you provide a URL for both "VerarbGewBergbauLaender.csv" and "DEU_adm1.shp" instead of the local file paths? This may mean you uploading them to Github or Dropbox, but without sharing the underlying data it will be difficult for helpers to give you a good answer.

Comment: you are right Nate. It´s my personal stuff. This is why I gave the data later on. But yes, I will change that. ah, ya, the shape file. good question... I´ll have a look.

Comment: It would be ideal if you share the data as R code, either using `data.frame(..)` to build it out or as the results from `dput()` instead of as a picture or straight text. It  minimizes the work you are asking the people helping to do.